# $\arcsin(x)$ without use of itself and $\sin^{-1}(x)$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I need to calculate $\arcsin(x)$ but I can only use $\sin(x)$, $\cos(x)$, basic operators, powers and roots. $\sin^{-1}(x)$ is not available. How can I do this?

In short, I need another way to calculate this:
$$2\arcsin\left(\frac{r}{d}\right)$$ without using $\arcsin$.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This question is not sufficiently specific. Do you have a particular problem in mind?

Comment: @Antonios-AlexandrosRobotis I have updated the question

Comment: Can we use Logarithms and Complex Number $i$?

Comment: Then we can write it as $$2\arcsin(\frac{r}{d}) = -2i\log(\sqrt{1 - (\frac{r}{d})^2} + i(\frac{r}{d}))$$

Comment: http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/archives/physics116A10/arc_10.pdf Provides the process how we can convert $\arcsin$ to a expression involving complex numbers.

Comment: @SoumalyaPramanik Sadly no, the programming language I am trying to use is very basic. In fact it isn't a programming language at all.

Comment: You can only evaluate $\sin x$ but you need to compute $\arcsin x$? Use the [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) starting with the interval $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. For faster convergence, use [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) with initial guess $u_0=0$ and iteration function $u_{n+1}=u_n - (\sin u_n-x)/\cos u_n$.

Comment: Can you use $\arctan $?

Comment: @user No sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\arcsin x = \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$

Only addition, multiplication, and division required!

If you only need an approximation to arcsine (as it appears, from the comments), then you don't need the whole series, just truncate after some number of terms to get an approximation.

$$\arcsin x = x + \frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{3x^5}{40}+\frac{5x^7}{112}+\cdots$$

Comment: I forgot about the Taylor series. Great observation here!

Answer (score 2):

You may also use Newton's method with starting point $z_0=\frac{3x}{2+\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ (provided by the Shafer-Fink inequality) - the sequence defined by
$$z_{n+1} = z_n-\frac{\sin(z_n)-x}{\cos(z_n)} $$
converges to $\arcsin(x)$ pretty fast.